# React setState of for deeply nested value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, setstate

I’ve got a very deeply nested object in my React state. The aim is to change a value from a child node. The path to what node should be updated is already solved, and I use helper variables to access this path within my setState.

Anyway, I really struggle to do setState within this nested beast. I    abstracted this problem in a codepen:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-villani-ddci9

In this example I want to change the child’s `changed` property of the child having the `id` `def1234`.

As mentioned the path is given: Fixed Path values: `Members, skills` and variable Path values: `Unique Key 1` (coming from `const currentGroupKey` and both Array position in the data coming from `const path`

This is my state object:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    group:
    {
      "Unique Key 1": {
        "Members": [
          {
            "name": "Jack",
            "id": "1234",
            "skills": [
              {
                "name": "programming",
                "id": "13371234",
                "changed": "2019-08-28T19:25:46+02:00"
              },
              {
                "name": "writing",
                "id": "abc1234",
                "changed": "2019-08-28T19:25:46+02:00"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Black",
            "id": "5678",
            "skills": [
              {
                "name": "programming",
                "id": "14771234",
                "changed": "2019-08-28T19:25:46+02:00"
              },
              {
                "name": "writing",
                "id": "def1234",
                "changed": "2019-08-28T19:25:46+02:00"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  };
}

handleClick = () => {
  const currentGroupKey = 'Unique Key 1';
  const path = [1, 1];
  // full path: [currentGroupKey, 'Members', path[0], 'skills', path[1]]
  // result in: { name: "writing", id: "def1234", changed: "2019-08-28T19:25:46+02:00" }

  // so far my approach (not working) also its objects only should be [] for arrays
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    group: {
      ...prevState.group,
      [currentGroupKey]: {
        ...prevState.group[currentGroupKey],
        Members: {
          ...prevState.group[currentGroupKey].Members,
          [path[0]]: {
            ...prevState.group[currentGroupKey].Members[path[0]],
            skills: {
              ...prevState.group[currentGroupKey].Members[path[0]].skills,
              [path[1]]: {
                ...prevState.group[currentGroupKey].Members[path[0]].skills[
                  path[1]
                ],
                changed: 'just now',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }));
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{this.state.group}</p>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change Time</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would appreciate any help. I’m in struggle for 2 days already :/

Comment: wow could you use some immutable libraries to handle the situation? The structures are quite messy here.

Comment: Never, worked with those before, what would you recommend?

Comment: Try immer.js. https://github.com/immerjs/immer#reactsetstate-example

Comment: is this the similar to: https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper?

Comment: Yeap. There are plenty of these kinds of libraries. Famous one: Immer.js and Immutable.js

Comment: I suggest you instead of doing this (update just the changes with setState), loop through your Members array with Array.map do the changes you want and setState whole array that returned of the map.

Comment: There are several bugs in your codepen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-bose-t2fug) is the fix using `reduceStatePath` that comes from a file I added called lib.js

Comment: @HMR thanks for that codepen. About the "//you forgot to bind handleClick so no this" it was my understanding that since I’m using an arrow method in the class I don’t need bind. And it indeed does work without binding.

Comment: @Kalaschnik You are correct, must have done that and forgot about it. Only that the data is a string so you need to JSON.parse in constructor and that `Unique key 1` does not exist on the data/state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using new dependencies and having to learn them you could write a helper function to deal with updating deeply nested values.

I use the following helper:

```js
//helper to safely get properties
// get({hi},['hi','doesNotExist'],defaultValue)
const get = (object, path, defaultValue) => {
  const recur = (object, path) => {
    if (object === undefined) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
    if (path.length === 0) {
      return object;
    }
    return recur(object[path[0]], path.slice(1));
  };
  return recur(object, path);
};
//returns new state passing get(state,statePath) to modifier
const reduceStatePath = (
  state,
  statePath,
  modifier
) => {
  const recur = (result, path) => {
    const key = path[0];
    if (path.length === 0) {
      return modifier(get(state, statePath));
    }
    return Array.isArray(result)
      ? result.map((item, index) =>
          index === Number(key)
            ? recur(item, path.slice(1))
            : item
        )
      : {
          ...result,
          [key]: recur(result[key], path.slice(1)),
        };
  };
  const newState = recur(state, statePath);
  return get(state, statePath) === get(newState, statePath)
    ? state
    : newState;
};

//use example
const state = {
  one: [
    { two: 22 },
    {
      three: {
        four: 22,
      },
    },
  ],
};
const newState = reduceStatePath(
  state,
  //pass state.one[1],three.four to modifier function
  ['one', 1, 'three', 'four'],
  //gets state.one[1].three.four and sets it in the
  //new state with the return value
  i => i + 1 // add one to state.one[0].three.four
);
console.log('new state', newState.one[1].three.four);
console.log('old state', state.one[1].three.four);
console.log(
  'other keys are same:',
  state.one[0] === newState.one[0]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update a deeply nested property inside of your state, you could use something like the `set` function from `lodash`, for example:

```js
import set from 'lodash/set'

// ...

handleClick = () => {
  const currentGroupKey = 'Unique Key';
  const path = [1, 1];

  let nextState = {...this.state}

  // as rightly pointed by @HMR in the comments,
  // use an array instead of string interpolation
  // for a safer approach

  set(
    nextState,
    ["group", currentGroupKey, "Members", path[0], "skills", path[1], "changed"],
    "just now"
  );

  this.setState(nextState)
}
```

This does the trick, but since `set` mutates the original object, make sure to make a copy with the `object spread` technique.

---

Also, in your `CodeSandbox` example, you set the `group` property inside of your `state` to a string. Make sure you take that `JSON` string and construct a proper JavaScript object with it so that you can use it in your state.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.setState = { group: JSON.parse(myState) }
}
```

---

Here's a working example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-pasteur-qfiuy?fontsize=14)

Comment: To use `set` (and `get`) from lodash passing a string as path instead of array you open yourself up for strange bugs when properties have dots in their property name: `{'prop.with.dots':22}`. Instead you should pass the path as array: `set(nextState, ['group',currentGroupKey,'Members',path[0],'skills',path[1],'changed']`

Comment: Yes, I've been meaning to make the edit but I am just getting the chance now. Also, using dots for object keys sounds like a bad decision made by a previous developer rather than an issue with the `lodash.set` method itself. Both solutions are valid and have their pros and cons. I prefer a solution that have worked for me before, you prefer to roll your own and that's great too. Thanks for contributing to this community!

Comment: You can't suggest limiting object key names because of lodash is a good thing, this is definitely a fault in lodash because JS allows it and sometimes you have no control over it (3rd party API). Lodash does offer passing an array, it should just remove the string path as it's not a stable way of getting/setting from valid JS objects.

Comment: I never suggested changing your code so that it works with `lodash`. JavaScript allows for different kinds of things that are not great, using dots in your object keys just sounds like a bad decision - just because you can, doesn't mean you should. JS allows to use `dot notation` for accessing object properties, but you can't do that with something like the following - `const obj = { 'a.b.c': 1 }`. This just simply wouldn't work: `console.log(obj.a.b.c)`. If JS allows using dots & it allows accessing properties using the `dot notation`, but I can't in this case, is it JavaScript's fault?