# Merge a nested subset object into deeply nested state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I get new data returned from a function which is a new chunk I would like to merge with my state.

I made a `jsbin` example with some dummy data:

https://jsbin.com/kufonikica/1/edit?js,console

This is my state object:

```
const state = {
  group: {
    Everything: {
      teams: [
        {
          title: "dev",
          id: "dev",
          member: [
            {
              title: "John doe",
              id: "adsfadsfqwerewqv"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "test",
          id: "test",
          member: [
            {
              title: "Jack",
              id: "3242ewrewr"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "sleep",
          id: "sleep",
          member: [
            {
              title: "Homer Simpson",
              id: "sadfasdfdsaf3"
            },
            {
              title: "John",
              id: "sadfasddddfdsa"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      title: "Everything is cool",
      key: "Everything"
    },
    Something: {
      teams: [
        {
          title: "dev",
          id: "dev",
          member: [
            {
              title: "Susan",
              id: "dsafadsf"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      title: "Something is cool",
      key: "Something"
    }
  }
};
```

Now, when something changed, I receive a new subset of `teams`. For example, a new chunk would look like:

```
const updatedSubsetState = {
  teams: [
    {
      title: "dev",
      id: "dev",
      member: [
        {
          title: "John doe",
          id: "adsfadsfqwerewqv"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "test",
      id: "test",
      member: [
        {
          title: "Jack",
          id: "3242ewrewr"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "sleep",
      id: "sleep",
      member: [
        {
          title: "Homer Simpson",
          id: "sadfasdfdsaf3"
        },
        {
          title: "John+++IS NOW UPDATED+++",
          id: "sadfasddddfdsa"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I also know the main group which should be updated: `const whichThingShouldUpdate = 'Everything'`

What is the correct way of merging these both objects to gain the entire new state yet with the updated line from the `updatedSubsetState`: `"John+++IS NOW UPDATED+++"` That means the resulting object should look like:

```
const state = {
  group: {
    Everything: {
      teams: [
        {
          title: "dev",
          id: "dev",
          member: [
            {
              title: "John doe",
              id: "adsfadsfqwerewqv"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "test",
          id: "test",
          member: [
            {
              title: "Jack",
              id: "3242ewrewr"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "sleep",
          id: "sleep",
          member: [
            {
              title: "Homer Simpson",
              id: "sadfasdfdsaf3"
            },
            {
              title: "John+++IS NOW UPDATED+++",
              id: "sadfasddddfdsa"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      title: "Everything is cool",
      key: "Everything"
    },
    Something: {
      teams: [
        {
          title: "dev",
          id: "dev",
          member: [
            {
              title: "Susan",
              id: "dsafadsf"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      title: "Something is cool",
      key: "Something"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: do you need to merge items in state.group.everything.teams[x].member with updatedSubsetState.teams[x].members or does updatedSubsetState.teams[x].members replace it?

Comment: @HMR I think—If I got you correctly—the subset can entirely replace the old state. I updated the question to better illustrate that.

Comment: Does updatedSubsetState only have a teams property or can there be other properties that you want to replace `state.group.Everything` with?

Comment: No it only has teams properties and only knows about the updated teams properties...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using setStatePath that I mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57737721/1641941). Using lodash set is more difficult because it doesn't take a callback as value.

So you can do:

```
reduceStatePath(
  state,
  ['group', 'Everything','teams'],
  () => updatedSubsetState.teams
),
```

If `updatedSubsetState` has multiple keys or if the `teams` key is dynamic you can do:

```
Object.entries(updatedSubsetState).reduce(
  (state, [key, value]) =>
    reduceStatePath(
      state,
      ['group', 'Everything'].concat(key),
      () => value
    ),
  state
)
```

Comment: I get an modifier is not a function. My function call looks like this:
this.setState(
            reduceStatePath(
                this.state,
                [
                    'group',
                    'Everything',
                    'teams',
                    teamsIndex,
                    'skills',
                    skillsIndex,
                    'changed',
                ],
                ['group', Everything, 'teams'],
                () => updatedSubsetState.teams
            ),
        );

Comment: then the 3rd argument you passed to reduceStatePath is not a function.

Comment: Updated the comment. the third argument is `() => draggedData.lanes`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not because the error is literally `modifier is not a function` and reduceState receives an argument named `modifier` which it expects to be a function. Maybe you could give me a pastebin link with some of the code?

Comment: HMR thank you very much for the help. I’ll setup another codesandbox. I was not aware that my former problem is that closely related. Give me 15 min.

Comment: Need to leave my workplace and need to figure out the problem so that that it is small but still representing my code 100%. Might take up to 2 hours. I would be so glad to get this solved...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-dew-0tqh7
It is actually about that `updatedSubsetState` contains a new location for a specific person in the array teams and in the array memeber. I already know how to get the new locations (see newTeamIndex, etc.). Yet, still the same task. The `updatedSubsetState` needs to get merged with the state. After that I can access the new position of that person and change its properties...

Comment: @Kalaschnik In that example you don't use updateSubState I changed it to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-euler-egu0e)

Comment: Thank’s a lot – You know why the first console log returns undefined?

Comment: @Kalaschnik Because [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asynchronous, if you want to log it you need to use a [callback](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-euler-egu0e)